# Ubuntu installation error and boot loader question

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 but after clicking on the installer, I'm getting these errors.

[image]

Should I be concerned about these errors if I were to install Ubuntu directly from the usb instead of testing and installing it that way?

Also I have a question about dual booting. When I dual booted Ubuntu with Windows a few years ago, the MBR got deleted when I uninstalled Ubuntu. Are there any easier solutions to getting the correct boot loader back besides using the Windows recovery disk?